# Invalid literal for base 10 error while iterating on map

Tags: python

I have a map of several integer values and I would like to iterate over it and print its values. I tried this:

```
n = map(int, input().split())

1 2 3 4 5

for i in n:
    print(i)
```

This gives me an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

Doing the same operation above by using `.strip()` does the job of printing the integers.

```
 del(n)
 n = map(int, input().strip().split())
 1 2 3 4 5

 for i in n:
     print(i)
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

What does an 'invalid literal for base 10' mean and why using `.strip()` fixes the error? Also, is a map object a single entity in Python since using `range(map)` gives error 'map' object cannot be interpreted as an integer?

```
for i in range(n):
    print(i)

TypeError: 'map' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, it works for me (the first part). The second part can't work because range takes an integer, not a map object.

Comment: Not reproducible. Printing `map(int, ['1', '2', '3', '4'])` for instance works fine.

Comment: Apologies for the major mistake gentlemen. It does seem that that inserting in `strip()` is necessary for the map to print values. But simply using `n = map(int, input().split())` gives error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '  '`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`map` returns a generator that you can consume once, not twice.

```
n = map(int, input().strip().split())   
print(*n)
```

will print them with a default seperator of `' '`. If you want to do 2+ things with the result of your map, store it in a list:

```
n = list( map(int, input().strip().split()) )
```

so you are not operating on a generator - the list will keep the values for you to use a second/multiple times.

This

```
for i in range(map(int, input().strip().split())):
    # do smth
```

does not work as map returns `<map object at 0x7f9ff77c12b0>` not an integer as needed for `range`.

Comment: That made things clear.

Answer (score 7):

From my previous experiences, you are probably consuming the map object before printing it out. `map` returns a consumable iterator so if you want to print the values of it, make sure you don't consume it.

For example,

```
>>> n = map(int, input().strip().split())
1 2 3 4 5

>>> for i in n:
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
5

>>> for i in n:
...     print(i)

# prints nothing
```

Comment: That's the most likely explanation for what's going on here. OP, always show us the complete code that's related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The second code does not work because range takes an **int object** not a **map object** and **n is a map object.**

The first part works for me.